# How to guarantee continuity of functions between one point compactifications?

Tags: general-topology

This is a homework question so I'd appreciate hints rather than full solutions.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the one-point compactifications of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ respectively.
Say a function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is such that $f(a)=\infty$ for some $a \in X$.

Prove $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff for each finite $M$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that the norm $|f(x)|>M$ whenever $d(x,a) < \delta$.

I can easily do the forwards direction, assuming $f$ is continuous and showing the criterion holds.  But I cannot figure out the backwards direction.

I took any open set $U$ containing infinity in $Y$, and tried to show it's preimage is open in $X$.  Clearly there is a $\delta$-ball surrounding the point a that is contained in the preimage of $U$, since that is what the criterion gives us,  but I can't see why any other point $a'$ in the preimage must have an open nbd contained inside it.

I know that $U = Y - K$  for some $K$ compact, which means closed and bounded. But I can't figure out how that helps.

Comment: You need "continuity at $a$", that means you don't need to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open $U\subset Y$ containing $\infty$, you only need to show that for such $U$ the set $f^{-1}(U)$ is a neighbourhood of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

So is this correct?

To show f is continuous at a, I need to take any open nbd U of f(a)=infinity, and find an open nbd of a contained in the preimage.

Since U is an open set containing infinity, it's complement is compact, and so therefore bounded by some ball of radius M. Then the criterion gives us that we have some delta-ball around a where all the points x inside that ball have |f(x)|>M, meaning f(x) is an element of U.  This means that our delta-ball is contained within the preimage of U, meaning we have shown continuity at the point a.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $O_M = \{y \in Y: y = \infty \text { or } |y| > M \}$ is an open neighbourhood of $\infty$ in $Y$, as its complement is $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^m: |y| \le M \}$ which is compact.

So if $f$ is continuous at $x=a$, there must be some $\delta$-neighbourhood of $a$ that sits inside $f^{-1}[O_M]$, and this is exactly what is asked for.

So suppose that $f$ satisfies the $M$-$\delta$ condition. Let $O$ be an open neighbourhood of $\infty$, so $\mathbb{R}^m \setminus O$ is compact, so there exists some $M > 0$ such that $\mathbb{R}^m \setminus O \subseteq \{y \in \mathbb{R}^m: |y| \le M \}$. So $O_M$ (which is the complement of the latter set) is a subset of $O$; the $\delta$ guarantees a neighbourhood of $a$ that maps into $O_M$ under $f$, so into $O$ as well. This shows the continuity at $a$.

The basic observation (included in the last paragraph) is that the sets $O_M$ form a local base (taking only $M \in \mathbb{N}$, we get a countable local base) at infinity, and the condition with $\delta$ and $M$ just garantuees that $f$ is continuous using the standard metric local base in $X$ and these complements of closed balls for $\infty \in Y$.